# Arguments dont get passed to middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a koa2js app, and using a modified version (which still works the same) of the hanrea/koa2-routing.

Using it like this:

```
app.route('/').get(function (ctx, next){console.log(arguments); await next();})
```

I get the `ctx, next` arguments. But when I use it like this:

```
app.route('/').get(async (ctx, next)=>{console.log(arguments); await next();})
```

or

```
app.route('/').get(super.someFunction(ctx, next))
```

The arguments don't get passed along.

**[EDIT]**
[Jim Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4878850/jim-wright)'s answer did it for me. Turns out you need to take a break from coding :-) once in a while to review the basic mistakes in code.

Comment: can u paste the stack you received?

Comment: I think you need to pass the middleware as a closure/callable? Here you are calling the function so passing the result to the middleware.

Comment: Arrow functions have lexically bound `arguments` so what you're probably receiving in the second snippet are the arguments passed to the implicit module closure for the Node.js script file.

Comment: @JimWright how do i pass it as a closure? any ideas are welcome

Comment: Also, `await next()` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i was thinking it just calls the next middleware?

Comment: The `await` is unecessary.

Comment: The `async` is also unnecessary. `app.route('/').get((ctx, next) =>
 { console.log(arguments); next(); });`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts ,  Nick -  I just put them there assuming i might need to pause the execution midway. Those aren't really an issue. I need to get the arguments tho. Any suggestions.

Comment: You start your "question" with an approach that does what you want, and you don't really ask a question. I fail to see the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function as a closure:

```
app.route('/').get(super.someFunction)
```

The above will work assuming that `someFunction` is defined like this:

```
function someFunction(ctx, next) {
    // My middleware logic...
    next();
}
```

This is because in javascript functions are first class citizens. This effectively means you can pass them around like variables. Take the following example:

```js
function addAbc(str) {
    return str + "abc";
}
function doSomething(str, closure) {
    // closure is actually the addAbc function before it has been called
    return closure(str);
}
console.log(doSomething("The first letters of the alphabet are ", addAbc));
// Notice the lack of () after the function name. It is being passed in as a variable!
```

For some more examples take a look at [the Mozilla documentation on callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

The issue with your code is that it is actually executing the function, and using the returned value as the callback, like in the following example:

```js
function myMiddleware() {
    return "middleware was executed";
}
function doSomething(middleware) {
    console.log(middleware);
    middleware();
}
console.log("Using callback function properly:");
doSomething(myMiddleware);
console.log("Using callback function wrongly:");
doSomething(myMiddleware()); // Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function
```